# PreprocessCore package

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and I got an assignment that includes a sourcecode.

Part of the source code includes the following line:

```
library(preprocessCore)
```

Then I have in my source code a definition of the following function:

```
quantile.normalize.raw.gtex <- function(edata.mat)

{
    norm_edata = normalize.quantiles(as.matrix(edata.mat))
    rownames(norm_edata) = rownames(edata.mat)
    colnames(norm_edata) = colnames(edata.mat)
    return(norm_edata)
}
```

Finally, I have an object being initialized to the output of this function, after sending a predefined parameter:

```
tissue.edata.qn = quantile.normalize.raw.gtex(tissue.edata)
```

From what I understand, the library function is supposed to include the function `normalize.quantiles`, which is called in the function that is defined in my source code.

However, when I run the line `library(preprocessCore)` I get the following error:

> Error in library(preprocessCore) :
>
> there is no package called ‘preprocessCore’

I also tried to run the rest of the code and got the error:

> Error in normalize.quantiles(as.matrix(edata.mat)) :
>
> could not find function "normalize.quantiles"

I looked for the **preprocessCore** online and eventually I tried to write `install.packages("preprocessCore")`, but I got a warning message that this package is only available in version 3.6.0 of R, even though I checked and this is the version that I have.

If somebody has any idea what the problem is, I will appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preprocessCore` package is available in **Bioconductor**. So, to install it, you need the following lines:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("preprocessCore")
```

After that, you can load the package using `library(preprocessCore)`

Hope it helps.